# Meaning of Spatial resolution (m) = 2 rng?

Tags: resolution, radar, specification, insar, synthetic-aperture-radar

I'm reading [a catalog about SAR sensors](http://www.crcsi.com.au/assets/Uploads/Files/Adjunct-Reference-1-SAR-Sensor-Specifications-FINAL.pdf).

On page 17, it is said that:

[image]

I've read the [PolSAR data format for UAVSAR](https://uavsar.jpl.nasa.gov/science/documents/polsar-format.html) before, But not the other [documentations](https://uavsar.jpl.nasa.gov/science/documents.html) related to InSAR, because I didn't need to.
And I'm really wondering

- What does `rng` mean?
- Is it an acronym for a phrase? Then which?

Comment: Range. At [eoPortal](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/airborne-sensors/uavsar) Table 1 shows Intrinsic resolution 1.8 m slant range. Some description of slant range can be found [here](http://www.radartutorial.eu/01.basics/Slant%20Range.en.html).

Comment: @Kazuhito oh thanks. I knew about ranges. (ie slant range and ground range) but I didn't think about it last night.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean it. Anyway they shouldn't have abbreviated it. There is plenty of space to fully write the word *range*.

Comment: @Kazuhito yeah, I don't understand, too. I'll have a more careful look on the links that you suggested.

Comment: @AndreSilva thanks! But I am afraid my point was only about its unnecessary abbreviation ... which frustrated us.